# Redirect Flutter SDK path when building iOS build?

Tags: ios, macos, server, flutter

I wrote a Flutter app using IntelliJ on my Linux machine. I need to build the ipa file for iOS devices, and I do not have a Mac.
I plan on using a "Mac in the cloud" server to prepare the release build for the App Store. I have been mapping out all of the steps that I need to do to do the whole process, and I got to wondering: if I am opening my project folders on a server somewhere, do I have to configure the path to the Flutter SDK that I will have to download on to server machine?

I have looked at the Flutter.io documentation, but did not find an answer to this question.

Goal: to generate a release build for iOS on server machine from the project folders that I used on my Linux machine to make release build for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question, IntelliJ seems to find the correct flutter path on its own somehow. It give me an error message after build command, but then continues using correct flutter path. I am pretty sure that I never told the program where to find flutter.